# Max length for decimal tetbox

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I would like to create a TextBox that allows users to key in decimal values. Now the catch is, I want to give maxlength to the integral part(value before decimal) so when i say the maxlength is 5

User can enter

```
.12
12345
12345.67
```

User should not be able to enter

```
123456
123456.78
```

I am handling the textbox keypress to restrict the alphabets

```
If Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) AndAlso Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> "."c Then
    e.Handled = True
End If

' only allow one decimal point
If e.KeyChar = "."c AndAlso TryCast(sender, TextBox).Text.IndexOf("."c) > -1 Then
    e.Handled = True
End If
```

Can somebody please help me with this maxlength part. Appreciate any help and directions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with the `MaxLength` property, the text box is simply looking at `String.Length`, whereas what you want is to actually parse the string into a decimal value and do some bounds checking on it.

You will need to do that in your key press event.  The simplest thing to do would be to do something like:

```
var value = Decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text);
if(value >= 99999)
     e.Handled = true;
```

That's not the exact algorithm you probably want, but you get the idea.

Comment: Maybe better using [`Decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) and `textBox1.Text.Trim()`?

Comment: @UweKeim  If he's already using the key press event to prevent the entry of characters (and presumably anything other than things that would make up a valid decimal value) then it's a bit redundant to use `TryParse()` and likely also `Trim()` (since he's probably already preventing spaces).

Comment: What if the texts get entered via the right-click context menu and the Paste command? ;-)

Comment: if the text=99999, you won't be able to add a decimal point and continue filling the decimal part

Comment: @UnLoCo I said that wasn't the exact algorith, but based on his textbox with MaxLength of 5, that would still be true.

Comment: @CodingGorilla Thanks! Only issue now is that, it validates only when i have already keyed in 123456. Can you suggest if i should be using a different event.

Comment: @Anoop Not sure what you mean.

Comment: @CodingGorilla When the keypress event is getting fired, the value on the textfield will not contain the character/number that's keyed in at that moment. Suppose my textbox already contains value of 12345, now when i press "6", the keypress fires, and textBox1.Text will contain only 12345, thus allowing 6 also to be typed in. Hope i make some sense

Comment: @Anoop Right, so you can take the current `textBox1.Text` and append the appropriate character (based on the key pressed), or you can also use the `textBox1.TextChanged` event.